# tomcat - start thread in servlet and send response

Tags: java, android, multithreading, servlets, httpclient

How can I start a thread which will run in the background but the response will be sent to the user immediately?

I'm trying to upload a file from an android device. While the uploading process works fine, I'd like to tell the user that the process has finished once the file has been uploaded from his end.

I have checked that the call to ServletFileUpload.parseRequest() is what takes a long time.

```
        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);

        List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
```

So basically I'm looking for a way where I can tell the user "hey you've done your part", now it's the servlet's turn to do all the processing.

but I can't because parseRequest blocks.

Am I wrong in that it blocks because that's when it's actually being sent by the device?

**Uploading on android:**

```
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            task.myPublishProgress(totalBytesRead, fileSize);

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            totalBytesRead+= bytesRead;

        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // close streams

        fileInputStream.close();

        dos.flush();

        Log.i(TAG ,"Database file with name " + this.fileName + " has been successfully written");

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        // retrieve the response from server

        int ch;

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){
            b.append( (char)ch );
        }

        dos.close();
```

**handling on server:**

```
                DiskFileItemFactory  fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory ();

            ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
            /*
             * Parse the request
             */
            System.out.println("parsing the request....");
            **List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);**
            FileItem item = (FileItem) items.get(0);
            fileName = item.getName();

            File file = new File(destinationDir, fileName);
            item.write(file);
```

I'd like the servlet not too block on parseRequest, but instead handle that in a thread perhaps, and send the response to the client.

thanks

Comment: Can you please give more details like what are you trying to do that and where are you struck?

Comment: @anubhava see edited question. let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @kkudi: Thanks, I don't know much about Android coding but is device sending AJAX request to your server an option? That way you don't have to deal with building this solution on server side.

Comment: The device is sending an HttpURLConnection, writes the data to the server and is awaiting for the response.

Comment: Ok in that case is using asynchronous http client an option for you? Please check https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Comment: I think I need an asynchronous server not a client or a way that the parseRequest method call is dealt with asynchronously. Perhaps in a different thread (hence asking my question in the first place). Well I could just not get a response at all from the client and that would somehow solve my problem.

Comment: The problem with doing it on server side is that you don't want to hang on the request but still want to return response (whenever its available). If request has been done with you won't be able to respond to client using same request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in standard HTTP. The response can only be sent when the request body has fully been consumed. As long as you don't call `uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);`, the files are not been uploaded. You would be lying if you tell "You're done!" prior this point.

Only *after* calling `uploadHandler.parseRequest(request)` and having the items, you could tell the user in all honesty that he's done. The remnant can however perfectly be done in a separate thread. I'd suggest to create a fixed threadpool for that which is managed by a `ServletContextListener`. However, I think this is a bit exaggerated when you aren't doing any expensive tasks with the uploaded files.

As to the *concrete* problem (that the application seems to do nothing while it is busy to upload the files), I'd rather suggest to solve the problem at the client side. Get the size of the files, get hold of the count of the bytes sent to the outputstream and then show some progress bar in the client side so that the client get informed about the progress.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing. I'm showing a Progress Dialog using the bytes sent to the output stream but that's just about it.You said yourself I would be lying that the files have been uploaded if I just tell the user that the upload process has finished only by updating a progress dialog using the number of bytes written to the output stream. It doesn't mean that the uploading process has been successful until after the request has been consumed and a response has been sent to the client.

Comment: This is not true. You seem to think that all files are already been sent to the server side at the point that Servlet's `doPost()` is been called. This is untrue. Right before you call `parseRequest()` the files are still on the client. Once you call `parseRequest()`, the server will start to read the request body with the uploaded files and thus the real byte streaming starts. Once the `parseRequest()` method is finished and the code moves on, all files are been read.

Comment: ah I see! So how do I get a hold of the number of bytes that have actually been processed by parseRequest? The only information I use for the progress dialog is the number of bytes read to the DataOutputStream as shown in the code in the client.

Comment: Create a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which wraps the `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()` in a `CountingInputStream` (part of commons-io which you should already have). Store a reference of it in the session before parsing and remove it after parsing. Then fire async/ajax requests on some servlet which checks it in the session by and returns the status.